# How to provide and use varargs or Iterable parameter for custom @Query in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA (currently 1.11.3.RELEASE) with Hibernate (currently 5.2.10.Final) as JPA implementation

I've got the following scenario as (simplified) example, first a simple User entity class:

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
private Long id;

private boolean active;

// getters/setters (not shown)

}
```

with a CRUD-based User repository. This user repository should provide methods to deactivate a user identified by its id:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

// deactivate single user
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE User u SET active = false WHERE u.id = ?1")
void deactivate(Long id);

// TODO how to provide a deactivateAll method
}
```

This solution is well described in the Spring Data JPA documentation using [@Query in its modifying form](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries).

What I missed in the docs is **how to provide a list of ids as varags or Iterable parameter** to **allow deactivation of multiple users at once**. *How can I do that?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a **comparable example** of a User repository doing this **in the Spring Data JPA source code** repository: [UserRepository.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/sample/UserRepository.java) e.g. using @Query like this:

```
@Query("select u from User u where u.id in :ids")
Collection<User> findByIdsCustomWithNamedVarArgs(@Param("ids") Integer... ids);
```

So **you can provide a list of ids either using varargs or Iterable<>** as following (in this case using the named parameters variant):

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE User u SET active = false WHERE u.id IN :ids")
void deactivateAll(@Param("ids") Long... ids);

@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE User u SET active = false WHERE u.id IN :ids")
void deactivateAll(@Param("ids") Iterable<Long> ids);
```